# sum array of elements without unwind in group by?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Below are the projected Result and  I want to get the sum of Expenses Amount where ExpenseType equal to "1" and the result should group by Type and Quarter. How to achieve this functionality without unwinding the Expenses Array.?

```
{
    "Type" : "CreditCard",
    "Quarter": "20201",
    "Expenses" : [ 
        {
            "ExpenseType" : "1",
            "Amount" : 123         
        },
        {
            "ExpenseType" : "2",
            "Amount" : 183          
        }
    ]
}

{
    "Type" : "Cash",
    "Quarter": "20202",
    "Expenses" : [ 
        {
            "ExpenseType" : "1",
            "Amount" : 345        
        },
        {
            "ExpenseType" : "2",
            "Amount" : 200         
        }
    ]
}
Expected Output:

{
  "Type" : "CreditCard",
  "Quarter": "20201",
  "Total":"123"
}

{
  "Type" : "Cash",
  "Quarter": "20202",
  "Total":"345"
}****
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Mechanism**

1. Group by Quarter and Tpy
2. Sum values

**Pipeline**

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  $group: {
    "_id": {
      "Quarter": "$Quarter",
      "Type": "$Type"
    },
    "Total": {
      $push: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$Expenses",
          initialValue: 0,
          in: {
            $cond: [
              {
                $eq: [
                  "$$this.ExpenseType",
                  "1"
                ]
              },
              {
                $add: [
                  "$$value",
                  "$$this.Amount"
                ]
              },
              {
                $add: [
                  "$$value",
                  0
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

### [Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rKwQK591LSW)

Comment: Thank you, @Minsky  this query is working. How to sum this value without group by. Getting exception if there are more no of records in the collection. please let me know if there is any workaround to bring the result without group by.

Comment: @SudheshGnanasekaran will take a look later today